# How to set snapshot limit dynamically for Firebase pagination

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, pagination, react-native-flatlist

I try to build a flatlist which receives images from Firebase which use pagination.
The images are sorted by timestamp in descending order, so that the newest images is shown on top.

```
this.imageSubscribtion = await this.ref
  .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
  .limit(this.state.limit)
  .onSnapshot(async querySnapshot => {
    let imagesProm = querySnapshot.docs.map(async doc => {
    
      let data = await doc.data()

      return {
       ...data
      };
    });

    let images = await Promise.all(imagesProm);
    this.setState(
      {
        pointer: querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1],
        images: images, //.reverse(),
        isLoading: false,
      }
    );
  });
```

If the user reaches the end of the list, it will load 30 items more.

```
if (this.state.pointer) {
  this.setState({refreshing: true}, async () => {
    let result = await this.ref
      .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
      .limit(30)
      .startAfter(this.state.pointer)
      .get();

    let imageRefs = result.docs.map(async doc => {
      let data = await doc.data()
      return {
        ...data
      };
    });
    let images = await Promise.all(imageRefs);
    let newImages = this.state.images.concat(images);
    this.setState(
      {
        pointer: result.docs[result.docs.length - 1],
        images: newImages,
        refreshing: false,
        limit: newImages.length,
      });
  });
}
```

This works quite good and all the new images are added correctly.

The problem starts when new images are uploaded. When the onsnapshot method of the imageSubscribtion is fired the new images are loaded, but again with the initial limit of 30 items.

If someone is viewing the images at the moment and is down below 30 images the flatlist is resetted to 30 images and he needs to scroll down again.

Is there a possibility to set the limit of the query dynamically? I also tried to define the query with startAt(this.state.pointer) but its not working because in the first fetch the pointer is still undefined.

Comment: For you to be able to use `startAt()` you would need to change the way you are performing the first query, so you have values from the beginning and avoid the`undefined`. Could you please take a look at this article [here](https://medium.com/@650egor/firestore-reactive-pagination-db3afb0bf42e) and check if it helps you? It provides some insights in dynamic pagination with Firestore.

Comment: thanks i'll have a look at it and respond later

Comment: I tried it and reversed the direction because my list is descending from top to bottom and new to old. But its not working as expected if new images are deleted or modified. Kind of stuck atm

Comment: Actually, what I meant from the beginning is not reverse the order from the data, but actually, configure your query to already have values when calling the `startAt()`. Have you tried that?